# how to override url_rewrite module rewrite method in magento2?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

In magento one `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite->rewrite` method

where I will find same method in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope, you want custom rewrite**

So, in this case, you have to use two class:

1.`Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite`

2.`Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite`

`Model\UrlRewrite` for saving the record and `Helper\UrlRewrite` use for validated the rewrite before save.

**Example:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Amit Bera
 */

namespace StackExchange\Magentodemo\Model;

/**
 * Description of CustomUrl
 *
 * @author Amit Bera
 */
class CustomUrl {

    const ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOM = 'custom';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite
     */
    protected $helperUrlRewrite;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory
     */
    protected $urlRewriteFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite $helperUrlRewrite,
            \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
            ) {

                $this->urlRewriteFactory = $urlRewriteFactory;
                $this->helperUrlRewrite = $helperUrlRewrite;
    }
    public function testCustomUrl()
    {
        $requestPath ='devamitbera';
        $storeId = 0; // if default then 0
        $targetPath = 'contact';
        $description ='Redirect devamitbera to contact us page';
        // 301 = Permanent redirection (301),
        // 302 = Temporary redirection (302)
        //  0 = for No redirection
         $redirect_type =  301;

        $urlRewrite = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create();
        $validated = $this->helperUrlRewrite->validateRequestPath($requestPath);
        if( $validated){
            $urlRewrite->setEntityType(self::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    ->setRequestPath($requestPath)
                    ->setTargetPath($targetPath)
                    ->setRedirectType($redirect_type)
                    ->setStoreId( $storeId)
                    ->setDescription($description);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to remove store "default" when rewrite method run  which i have done in magento1 in below file
Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite->rewrite

Comment: Donot understant what u want to achive. Also `rewrite` deprecated function  at magento 1.x see https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php#L196.So implement  logic basic of function is not  good idea

Comment: Hi @amith can you please help on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/234836/magento-2-unable-to-get-theme-header-and-footer-for-custom-email-template